# Convert time from readable to unix time

Tags: python-3.x

I have this string **2018-01-01T14:50:00.000+05:00** or **2018-01-01 14:50:00** purpose is convert it to unix time. Help me =(

Comment: You have to show us what you've done so far. I can recommend using `strptime` method, but I can't write everything for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is module called time. Which gives the time in Unix.

use the sample code below for your scenario

```
import time
a=time.strptime('2018-05-01 14:25:00',"%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S")
print(time.mktime(a))
```

The output of this will be

```
1515142500.0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
def toUnix(str):
        if 'T' in str:
                str = str.replace('T', ' ')[0:19]
        return int(time.mktime(time.strptime(str, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')))

str1 = '2018-01-01T14:50:00.000+05:00'
str2 = '2018-01-01 14:50:00'

print(toUnix(str1))
print(toUnix(str2))
```